# Multiple ResultSet in EntityFramework

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework 4 for one of my projects. I am looking for the solution to reduce the database calls by returning multiple resultset. How can i achieve this using Entity Framework.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try using Stored Procedures with [EF Extensions](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFExtensions).
[This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/meek/archive/2008/03/26/ado-entity-framework-stored-procedure-customization.aspx) deals with EF Extensions, it contains Multiple Result Sets section as well.